# adding custom UIButton to UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

So the code I have is as follows:

```
// Create a containing view to position the button
    UIView *containingView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 23.5, 21.5)] autorelease];

    // Create a custom button with the image
    UIButton *button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Settings.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(settings) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(-19, -3, 21.5, 21.5)];
    [containingView addSubview:button];

    // Create a container bar button
    UIBarButtonItem *containingBarButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:containingView] autorelease];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = containingBarButton;
```

The issue is that my Settings.png original image size is 21.5, 21.5 and there fore the button is super hard to click. I have to tap really hard in order to trigger the UITouchUpInside to be triggered. This will clearly be rejected if I put it in the app store, as it is not in compliance with apple's HIG. Is there a way around this? I still need to use UIView as the container for the UIButton as I'd like to position it correctly on the UINavigationBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set a bigger fram to the button like 40,40 and set the content mode to be the center so the image will apear to be in the center.

`button.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;`

Tell me if that helped